# Shorthand Preg Match Rule for Identifying URLs

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

lets say I have the array:

```
[test1] = '/'
[test2] = '/foo'
[test3] = '/foo/*'
[test4] = '/bar/*'
[test5] = '/baz/*/bar'
```

what is the valid grep rule that these need to be converted into that would satisfy performing a `preg_match` function (with the rule as the pattern) against an input so the following inputs would return. as in, what does do the rules need to be encapsulated in, and what do the `*`s need to be replaced with?

```
input          :   returned
/              :   test1
/foo           :   test2
/foo/bar       :   test3
/foobar        :   none
/bar           :   test4
/bar/foo       :   test4
/barfoo        :   none
/baz/foo/bar   :   test5
/baz//bar      :   none
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I have done this:

```
<?php
$urlRule = str_replace('/', '\/', $urlRule);
$urlRule = '/^('.str_replace('*', ')(.*)(', $urlRule).')$/';

if (count(preg_grep($urlRule, array($url))) > 0) { ...
```

for each rule, but I did need to include

```
[test4] = '/bar'
```

in order to achieve

```
input          :   returned
/bar           :   test4
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace with:

```
[^/]+
```

This says *a non-empty string of non-slash characters*.  I'm making assumptions based on your last example (`/baz//bar` returning "none").

Of course, escape the slash if need be.

Comment: ah cool, works in expresso. what needs to be done to convert it to a PCRE format?

Answer (score 1):

I think to extract `path` and `filename` from the string may be better:

`^(\/(?:[^\\/:*?"<>|]+\/)*)([^\\/:*?"<>|]+)*$`

group 1: `path`
group 2: `filename`

use these information to do table look up(e.g hash array)